# Цикл foreach input заполнение данных

Tags: php, sql

циклом вывожу элементы с базы по номеру id то потом не знаю как сохранить назад изменение

вот код:

```
if ( $ident == $id ) {
foreach ($file as $rend) {
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td><img src="'.$rend['filename'].'" width="60px" height="60px" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="'.$rend['top'].'"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="'.$rend['index'].'"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="'.$rend['id'].'"></td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
}
```

Мне нужно после нажатия кнопки сохранить, чтобы все те элементы которые я изменил в input'ax (top, index) сохранились в базу под своими id.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: никто не может помочь?

Comment: тут дело не в том, что не могут помочь, а в том, что вы не знаете самых базовых вещей о программировании под веб. Это все равно если бы студент первокурсник спросил "я хочу сделать черную дыру, которая работала бы по средам с трех до восьми, подскажите как?".  Вот что на это отвечать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Для начала вам надо понять, что PHP - это серверный язык. Он отрисовывает HTML страницу и, через веб-сервер, отдает ее клиенту. На стороне клиента PHP не работает.
2. Изучите как работает тег [FORM](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form). В вашем случае проще всего использовать его.
3. Вам будет необходимо написать еще один PHP-скрипт, который будет принимать эту заполненную форму и обрабатывать заданные значения. Тут вам помогут знания о массивах [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php) и [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте тег form. Добавляйте ID в name в каждом input. Сам массив сохраняйте в сессии. Желательно чтобы ключами массива были ID элемента.
Пример реализации:

```
  <?php  foreach ($file as $rend) : ?>
       <tr>
          <td><img src="<?php echo $rend['filename']; ?>" width="60px" height="60px" /></td>
                <td><input name="top_<?php echo $rend['id']; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $rend['top']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input name="index_<?php echo $rend['id']; ?>"  type="text" value="<?php echo $rend['index']; ?>"></td>
                <td><input name="id_<?php echo $rend['id']; ?>"  type="text" value="<?php echo $rend['id']; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Принимать и обрабатывать в цикле (упрощенно, проверки сами добавите) (например если отправка POST запросом):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $value = strip_tags($value); 
$tmp = explode('_', $key);
//$tmp[0] - название поля, $tmp[1] - ИД элемента
//проверяем изменился ли элемент
if($_SESSION[название массива][$tmp[0]][$tmp[1]] != $value){ сохраняем... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с той же ситуацией, когда при отправке данных с формы отправляется только данные выведенные циклом foreach последнего инпута.

решается это очень просто. Надо чтобы у каждого выводимого foreach-ем инпута были уникальные атрибуты name.

Сделал это так:

```
$i=1;
            foreach($goods as $item){
                
                if($item['id'] and $item['name']){
                ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="admin"><input name='<?php echo "ID".$i;?>' type='text' size='3' value='<?echo $item['id'];?>'/></td>
        
        <td class="admin"><textarea name='<?php echo "text_zadachi".$i;?>' cols="auto" rows="auto"><?echo $item['text_zadachi'];?></textarea></td>
        
        <td class="admin"><?echo $item['status'];?>
        <select name='<?php echo "status".$i;?>'>
                    <option value="1">Выполнено</option>
                    <option value="0">Не выполнено</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
                <?
                $i++;}
            }
            ?>
```

т.е. по факту у тебя получиться первое

```
ID1 text_zadachi1 status1
ID2 text_zadachi2 status2
```

и т.д.

Запись в БД так же осуществлять циклом

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
            $id=$_POST['ID'.$i];
            $status=$_POST['status'.$i];
            $text_zadachi=$_POST['text_zadachi'.$i];
            тут вызов метода записи в БД
}
```

таким образом он их все поочередно запишет в базу данных.